# checkmark is not shown in django form

Tags: python, django

I created contact form but checkmark is not showing the option and the box is very narrow. So when login as admin and try to add a contact, I don't see options in there. Here is models.py and forms.py and screenshot.

[image]

**models.py**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Contact(models.Model):

    
    LOCATION_INHOME = (
        ('kitchen', 'Kitchen'),
        ('bathroom', 'Bathroom'),
        ('bedroom', 'Bedroom'),
        ('livingroom', 'Living Room'),
        ('basement', 'Basement'),
        ('garage', 'Garage'),
        ('office', 'Office'),
        ('hallway', 'Hallway'),
        ('stairway', 'Stairway'),
        ('recreationroom', 'Recreation Room'),
        ('closet', 'Closet'),
        ('other', 'Other'),
    )


    
    location_in_home = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
    

    
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    
    model = Contact
    fields = '__all__'
        
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Contact


class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = [

            'location_in_home',

        ]
        
        widgets = {
            'location_in_home': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
```

Here is the admin.py

```
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_filter = ('location_in_home')


admin.site.register(Contact, ContactAdmin)
```

Comment: Share the `ModelAdmin`

Comment: Do you have any `Location` created?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added admin.py

Comment: @sudden_appearance no, it is just form in admin so Loacation is passed through location_in_home = models.ManyToManyField(Location)

Answer (score 1):

The selection box is empty because there are no values in the `Location` model.  Many-to-many models are for cases where you will be dynamically create instances that can be linked via the M2M relation, rather than static choices as you've created in `LOCATION_INHOME`.  If you want to have a select multiple form field with static options, you'll need to use a 3rd party package like https://pypi.org/project/django-select-multiple-field/.  If you want to use dynamic choices with a M2M relation, you'll need to populate those options in the `Location` model first.

Comment: I think the problem is not that it is empty, but that it does not show checkboxes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think there are two problems, and we each addressed one of them.  The poster noted that there were no checkboxes and also that there were no options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the form on the [**`.form`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) of the `ModelAdmin`:

```
from django.contrib import admin


@admin.register(Contact)
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ContactForm
    list_filter = ('location_in_home', )
```

It will of course only render options if there is at least one location you have constructed.

otherwise you just constructed a form. But you can create zero, one, or multiple `ModelForm`s for the same model, these do not do anything unless you use these in a view, admin, etc.